# Stack pointer misalignment in aarch64 EL1

Tags: rust, arm, raspberry-pi3, memory-alignment, bare-metal

I am working on a low level program in rust on a Raspberry pi. I have been able to use UART and other features when running in EL2. I have been trying to transition to EL1. I am able to blink and LED from EL1 however whenver I call a function that uses the stack pointer, I get error code `0b100110`, which indicates a "SP alignment fault exception." I have tried setting the stack pointer from EL1, which works, however I still get the exception. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Here is my `start.s`:

```
.section ".text.boot"

.global _start

_start:
    // read cpu id, stop slave cores
    mrs     x1, mpidr_el1
    and     x1, x1, #3
    cbz     x1, 2f
    // cpu id > 0, stop
1:  wfe
    b       1b
2:  // cpu id == 0

    // set stack before our code
    ldr     x1, =_start
    //msr     SPSel, xzr //use sp_el0 as the default sp
    mov     sp, x1

    // clear bss
    ldr     x1, =bss_start
    ldr     w2, =bss_size
3:  cbz     w2, 4f
    str     xzr, [x1], #8
    sub     w2, w2, #1
    cbnz    w2, 3b

    // set up exception handlers and jump to Rust, should not return
4:  ldr     x0, =_exception_vector
    msr     VBAR_EL1, x0
    ldr     x0, =HEAP_START
    b       main
```

Here is `start.rs`:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn main(heap_start: usize) {
    if cpu::el() == 2 {
        // Counter and Timer Hyp Control
        // allow el 1 and 0 access to the timer and counter reigsters
        write!("CNTHCTL_EL2", read!("CNTHCTL_EL2") | 0b11);

        // set offset to 0
        write!("CNTVOFF_EL2", 0);

        // allow el1 and 0 to use the fancy SIMD and FP registers (I paid for them, I'm damned well going to use them)
        write!("CPTR_EL2", read!("CPTR_EL2") | (0b11 << 20));
        write!("CPACR_EL1", read!("CPACR_EL1") | (0b11 << 20));

        // set el1 to 64 bit execution
        // 31: 64 bit execution, 1: Set/Way Invalidation Override
        write!("HCR_EL2", (1 << 31) | (1 << 1));

        // Saved program status register
        // fake an exception to enter EL1
        // 9-6: DAIF
        // 5: Res0
        // 4: 0b0: AArch64 execution state
        // 3-0: SP: 0b0100 = EL1t = sp_el0
        write!("SPSR_EL2", 0b1111000100);

        // 4: SA0
        // 3: SA
        //write!("SCTLR_EL1", read!("SCTLR_EL1") | 0b11000);

        write!("ELR_el2", init_el1 as *const () as usize);

        cpu::eret();
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn init_el1() {
    let mmio = MMIOController::default();
    let gpio = GPIOController::new(&mmio);
    let status_light = StatusLight::init(&gpio);
    let timer = Timer::new(&mmio);

    blink_sequence(&status_light, &timer, 250);
    use_uart();
}

#[inline(never)]
#[no_mangle]
pub fn use_uart() {
    let mmio = MMIOController::default();
    let gpio = GPIOController::new(&mmio);
    let timer = Timer::new(&mmio);
    
    let mut uart = UARTController::init(&gpio, &mmio);

    uart.putc('f');
}

pub fn blink_sequence(status_light: &StatusLight, timer: &Timer, interval: u64) {
    status_light.set_green(OutputLevel::High);

    timer.delay(interval);

    status_light.set_green(OutputLevel::Low);
    status_light.set_blue(OutputLevel::High);

    timer.delay(interval);

    status_light.set_blue(OutputLevel::Low);
    status_light.set_red(OutputLevel::High);

    timer.delay(interval);

    status_light.set_red(OutputLevel::Low);
}
```

and this is the llvm arch specification JSON I have been using:

```json
{
    "llvm-target": "aarch64-unknown-none",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "env": "eabi",
    "vendor": "unknown",
    "arch": "aarch64",
    "linker-flavor": "ld",
    "linker": "aarch64-none-elf-ld",
    "pre-link-args": {
        "ld": [
            "-Taarch64-raspi3.ld"
        ]
    },
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128",
    "executables": true,
    "relocation-model": "static",
    "features": "+strict-align,+neon,+fp-armv8"
}
```

Comment: You know the rule, right?  Whenever you execute a load or store with `sp` as the base register, then `sp` must be 16-byte aligned.  So unless `_start` is 16-byte aligned, then the first load or store to the stack will fault.  Simplest solution is probably just to align it: replace `mov sp, x1` by `and sp, x1, #-16`.

Comment: @NateEldredge _start is 0x80000 and even when I set the sp to that after the el1 return I get the exception

Comment: Have you tried to read same address by using other register than `sp` ? You would know is that problem with `sp` or MMU. BTW, when doing all that system register writing in the end writings should be enforced with data and instruction barriers

Comment: @user3124812 I have not yet set up the mmu. Might this be the problem? Also, how do I enforce data and instruction barriers?

Comment: `dsb`, `isb` - data and instruction barriers respectively. Where do you actually setting `sp_el1` ? `mov     sp, x1` set stack only for current `EL` (presumably `EL3`), not for all EL-s

Comment: @user3124812
where should I put the instruction barriers?
Also, I thought that unless specified each El uses the same sp. I have tried setting the sp after the exception return, however that has no effect.

Comment: @user3124812 Also, the pi boots in EL2

Comment: Could the issue be that I have not done anything with the cache and mmu settings?

Comment: Why are you setting _start address for stack. Isn't that where your code starts? How sure are you your SP has the address which is 16 byte aligned? Register SPSel.SP needs to be set to 0x1 to access respective EL SP else it should be set to zero to access SP_EL0 at all ELs. 
You can disable SP alignment check by setting SCTLR_ELx.SA to 0 for respective ELx and SCTLR_EL1.SA0 to 0 to disable for EL0